# RegEx with a string

Tags: php, regex

So I have a random of strings and I need to parse them, let's take an example:

```
This string - DeleteMe please and some other text
```

So I want to find `DDeleteMe please and some other text` and remove it, because all I need is `This string`

Comment: Please, I am so curious: Do you only want everything before the `-` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So everything before the dash `-` or how does `DeleteMe please and some other text` qualifies to be deleted?

If so, you need no regex, you can do it with [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$string = "This string - DeleteMe please and some other text";
$string = trim(substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '-')));
```

You could also use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$parts = explode('-', $string);
$string = trim($parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$fixed_string = preg_replace("(\s-.*)$", "", $your_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex.

```
$str = 'This string - DeleteMe please and some other text';
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-') - 1);
```

Comment: What about `'This string-DeleteMe'` ? Would result in `This strin`.

Comment: In the example, the delimiter is ' - '.  If that's not what's intended, Uffo should clarify.

Comment: No what I meant was: `substr` gives you the substring **up to** (excluding) a certain index. In your example you subtract one, which removes (in case the previous character to the index is not a space) one character too much.

Comment: Felix, I'm aware of how `substr` works.  As I said, in the original example the delimiter is ' - ' (i.e. space dash space).  I wrote my code to work with that (note the lack of trim).

Comment: Oh ok, in the comments, I could not see that you mean the dash with spaces... you should have used `' - '` ;) Ok never mind...

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('\s*-\s*DeleteMe.*$','', $str)
```